# Using unnormalized log likelihood for model comparison with different features?

Tags: regression, feature-selection, model-comparison, likelihood

Is it possible to directly use the log likelihood from fitting a model, for the purpose of model comparison?  For example, if I'm using a logistic regression model, and I want to see if adding features is beneficial.  So I essentially would have 2 models (of the same type) with 2 feature sets, where one model's feature set is a subset of the other's.  Could I compare directly the log likelihoods returned by fitting these models, or do I need to normalize by DOF?  (The models would be fit on the same dataset, but DOF would differ because the number of features and thus number of parameters in the model would be different.)